# HTML CSS Slant / bevel

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create something like the following in pure html / css? 
[image]

I want to do this reponsive and full (100%) width (100px biggest left corner, smallest 50px right, something like that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reach the following result by transforming (rotating) multiple div's

https://jsfiddle.net/6hyrt8ck/

```
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue {
    background: blue;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 110%;
    height: 200px;
}

.green {
    background: green;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    width: 110%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Cool, never knew about this.